# Sum automatically after adding new row in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, row, formula

I am trying to use this `=SUM(C2:OFFSET(C10,-1,0))` but I am getting an error:

`We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert function on the formulas tab to fix it, or click help for more info on common formula problems. You type: =1+1, cell shows: 2. To get around this, type an apostrophe (') first: '=1+1, cell shows =1+1.`

I want it to show 2, I do not want it to show the formula.. Frustrating.

Anyone have the solution to this?

Clarification: 
I want a total (sum) in cell C10. I want the sum of C2 till C9. I want C10 to shift down each time I add a new row, and it automatically sums that newly added row(cell e.g. C10 now) in cell C11(total)

Comment: `I want it to show 2` - clarify please. Try to use `Index` instead `Offset` : `=SUM(C2:INDEX(...))`

Comment: I get the same error with index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: =SUM(Table3[Hours]) where table3 is column C and hours is the name in row 1, column C